# "#{rolebean.roleId}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'roleBean' resolved to null

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, managed-bean, viewparams

This is my xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
 <f:viewParam name="roleid" value="#{roleBean.roleid}"/>
 <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{warManagedBean.generatewar()}"/>
 </f:metadata>
```

This is my code in

```
@ManagedBean(name = "roleBean")
@SessionScoped
public class RoleBean implements Serializable{

    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;
    private String roleid;
```

Here i am trying to pass the id as a parameter to next page and it should retrieve values based on that id.
When i pass the bean id as a parameter to next page i get error

"#{rolebean.roleId}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'roleBean' resolved to null

This is the value from the column from the first xhtml page which i carry to next xhtml

```
<h:column>
 <f:facet name="header">
 <h:outputText value="RoleID" />
 </f:facet>
 <h:link outcome="info">
 <h:outputText value="#{roleBean.roleid}" style="white-space:nowrap"></h:outputText>
  <f:param name="roled" value="#{roleBean.roleid}">
</f:param>
  </h:link>
 </h:column>
```

Comment: Code doesn't match the error. Is it `#{bean}` or `#{beanBean}`?

Comment: /info.xhtml @12,81 value="#{roleBean.roleId}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'roleBean' resolved to null::  complete error line

Comment: `roleId` (in xhtml) is not the same as `roleID` (in bean). Not sure if it related to message.

Comment: They are actually same. i ve posted it wrongly. Edited now

Comment: provided some more info n code

Comment: Still not correct: in `f:viewParam` is **rolebean**, but in `h:outputText` and `ManagedBean` is **roleBean**.

Comment: Lesson for future questions: **copypaste real working code unmodified** instead of using the question editor as code editor. Otherwise your chances on getting an answer will greatly implode due to all those red herrings in the code caused by incapability of writing valid code off top of head. See also the introduction of the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: BalusC - i ll keep that in mind from now on. Anyways, my issue is resolved. Thanks all :)